# Can't trigger condition in decision table

Tags: java, drools

I can't seem to trigger my condition when I tried to put it in a decision table. The condition works fine from a `.drl` file but I just can't seem to make it work through a decision table. Here are the details of my code:

**Decision table:**
[image]

**Class:**

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.kie.api.KieServices;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieContainer;
import org.kie.api.runtime.KieSession;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
        KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession("ksession-dtables");

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put("companyCode", "MP");

        System.out.println(map.get("companyCode"));

        kSession.insert(map);
        kSession.fireAllRules();

        System.out.println(map.get("companyCode"));
    }
}
```

Somehow this is the only output I get:
[image]

The output I expect will be something like this:

```
MP
Company is MP
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: i mean it kinda tells you what to do...

Comment: @GutZuFusss I'm sorry I didn't quite get what you meant

Comment: So as a condition you check that `map.get("companyCode") == $param` and then as an action you `map.put("companyCoode", $param)`, and somehow you expect `$param` to magically change values between the condition and action?

Comment: Yeah. I'm quite new using decision tables or drools so I really don't understand how that `$param` works. I assumed that it will take up the values from `C10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it and it was a very noob mistake.

The value in cell C1 must contain the package where the decision table is. No wonder I can't trigger any condition at all.

Thanks for anyone who was looking to solve this.

[image]